# getElementById doesn't find results

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I am trying to parse a xml file by the id of all the tags.
Here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <zones>
    <bedroom id="0">
       <fan id="00">on</fan>
       <tv id="01">off</tv>
    </bedroom>
    <hall id="1">
    <tube id="10">on</tube>
    <bulb id="11">off</bulb>
    <fan id="12">on</fan>
    <tv id="13">on</tv>
    <ac id="14">on</ac>
    </hall>
    <kitchen id="2">
    <freez id="20">on</freez>
    </kitchen>
    <toilet id="3">
        <bulb id="30">on</bulb>
    </toilet>
    <bathroom id="4">
        <heater id="40">on</heater>
    </bathroom>
   </zones>
```

And here is my code..

```
     <html>
     <head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" > </head>
     <body>

      <script type="text/javascript" for="window" event="onload">
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","home.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

        document.write("<table border='1'>");
        var x=xmlDoc.getElementById("0");
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        { 
            document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write("fan");
                document.write("</td><td>");

                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("fan")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
               document.write("<tr><td>");
               document.write("tv");
               document.write("</td><td>");
               document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("tv")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
               document.write("</td></tr>");
       }

       var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("hall");
       for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
       { 
            document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write("tube");
                document.write("</td><td>");

                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("tube")  [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

                document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write("bulb");
                document.write("</td><td>");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("bulb") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

               document.write("<tr><td>");
               document.write("fan");
               document.write("</td><td>");
               document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("fan")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

               document.write("<tr><td>");
               document.write("tv");
               document.write("</td><td>");
               document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("tv")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

               document.write("<tr><td>");
               document.write("ac");
               document.write("</td><td>");
               document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ac")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

               document.write("</td></tr>");
         }

         var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("kitchen");
         for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
         { 
            document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write("freez");
                document.write("</td><td>");

                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("freez") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
         }

         var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("toilet");
         for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
         { 
            document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write("bulb");
                document.write("</td><td>");

                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("bulb") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
         }

         var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bathroom");
         for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
         { 
            document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write("heater");
                document.write("</td><td>");

                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("heater") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
         }

       document.write("</table>");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that when i implement my code with

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("bedroom");
```

everything work fine. But when i change that to

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementById("0");
```

nothing is shown in the browser. So please help me over it, am stuck on this.

Comment: This much use of `document.write` should be considered a criminal act.

Comment: The title is confusing. You probably mean javascript's **getElementById**.

Comment: Did you use the correct spelling getElementById() instead of getElementsById()?

Comment: @TJ. - It actually [has one](http://es.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php). But this question is not even related to PHP.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario : Thanks, I've changed my comment.

Comment: Don't use all those `document.write` statements, create a string instead and call `document.write` once at the end.

Comment: It works on servers. See my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer please see it. It might solve your problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getElementById returns an element which has an attribute that is of type "ID", not an attribute whose name is "ID". Without a DTD to go with your XML file, you have no attributes with the defined type, so getElementById will always return null. http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/getElementById

W3Schools does a pretty good job of explaining how to use a DTD. http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp

I would suggest that if you go this route that you consider using a more generic name for your XML elements and use an attribute to describe what room or applicance that element is referrring to (for example, instead of <bedroom id="0"> use <zone room="bedroom" id="0"> or instead of <fan id="00"> use <appliance name="fan" id="00">), otherwise your DTD will be larger and harder to maintain than it really needs to be.

Comment: Correct answer. Just because an attribute (in XML) is named "id" doesn't make it an ID attribute. You either need a DTD, or consider changing the attribute name to xml:id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i also went through the link that you had mentioned. Can you please tell me more about DTD. I mean how can i use it here. I also tried xml:id but all in vain...

Comment: I'm added to my answer a link to using a DTD as well as a suggestion if you decide to use a DTD.

Comment: It works without DTD. I got an output of a table. See my answer

Comment: This does work without a DTD in Safari and Chrome, however without the DTD you just get a blank page in Firefox and Opera, or at least I did. I'm not sure about Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have three errors:

---

1. On line 15, you are using:

   ```
   var x=xmlDoc.getElementsById("0");
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   var x=xmlDoc.getElementById("0");
   ```

   If you haven't spotted the difference:

   You are using `getElementsById`

   When you should be using `getElementById()`

   [Here is MDN documentation for `getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)
2. Is the file on your computer, or is it on a server (including home servers (XAMPP, easyPHP etc.))

   `XMLHttpRequest()` will only work if it is on a HTTP server.

   I get these errors:
   [image: errors]

   You can install one of these:

   - [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
   - [easyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/)
   - [Apache Server](http://apache.org/)

   I recommend using XAMPP or easyPHP because they are a lot more easy to setup.

   Then put your XML and HTML files in your htdocs folder.

   Finally, go to your server and navigate to your HTML file.

   It works on mine:

   > Output on the HTML file:
   >
   > [image: Look, it works!]
3. You will need a DTD in the file to make it work in some browsers or you can change your `id` attributes to `xml:id`. It will work in most (maybe all) modern browsers.

---

**UPDATE:** The OP has changed the code from `getElementsById()` to `getElementById()`.

Comment: @AMUL OK, that was by looking over it. I'll try with jsfiddle or something like that

Comment: I tried doing it by copying xml and html file in htdocs folder, but again same output

Comment: @AMUL What are you using Apache, easyPHP, XAMPP ore something else?

Comment: I am using apache... but that id part still hasn't worked for me. Is  there any other solution for it.???

Comment: @AMUL You did go to [localhost](http://localhost/) or [127.0.0.1](http://127.0.0.1/), right, and not just open it with the file:// URI

Comment: @AMUL what browser are you using?

Comment: Yeah it was the problem of chrome browser. It worked fine on Firefox.... and i seriously have no idea of what actually would be the reason behind it.

Comment: @AMUL was it your setup of chrome or chrome in general?

Answer (score 2):

Please use 
getElementById

Not 
getElementsById

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tried without 's' but still it doesn't works

Answer (score 2):

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsById("0")
```

It should be

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementById("0")
```

not `getElementsbyId`

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tried without 's' but still it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

`var x=xmlDoc.getElementById("0");`

the Alphabet character is very important